# "I am a beneficiary from" or "I benefited from"?

Tags: non-native-english

Which is more native like?

I personally am a beneficiary of the good policies he conducted.

or

I personally benefited from the good policies he conducted.

Comment: Well, "I personally is" isn't going to win any awards.

Comment: "I prersonally is" needs to be "I personally am" to be correct English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comment on above:
beneficiary is a noun:   " Herb was the primary beneficiary in Jacks will.."
benefit is a noun and a verb: as in " my jobs benefits are..."
                             " the main benefit of living in the city is.."
                            "the benefit of knowing Mary-Lou is..."
benefit is a verb in:  " I benefit from my acquaintance with John by..."

In the above examples the adverb "personally" is misplaced. Also "policies he conducted" is a bit top heavy. Better would be:

"I am personally a beneficiary of his good policies". Splitting " I am " to insert an adverb in between is not done. The first person singular of the verb " to be", is "I am" and an adverb qualifies the verb and is stated AFTER the verb.The usual cadence is NOUN, VERB, ADVERB. The exception would be if you used NOUN and a verb in the imperfect, conditional or future tense, then adverb. In this case you would say:

" I will happily go ....." to follow as in: 
" I would happily say..."
" I was happily thinking this was a one-way street"...

Then remember too, that you can purposefully break grammar rules for emphasis.

" I purposely decided to break the rules"  rather than,
" I decided purposely to break the rules" which is correct but lacks emphasis.

ENGLISH is not an easy language to learn !

Answer (score 0):

I am a beneficiary OF
I benefitted  FROM

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential parts? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: My comments are made with reference to THE OXFORD ENGLISH DICTIONARY, of course and not the WEBSTER VERSION  thereof.

Comment: I see. Can you try to expand your answer using the source? I think you received one downvote due to the length of the answer. BTW, I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Please incorporate your sources in your answer, using a few good answers as models.  The answer doesn't have to be long.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the examples you quote are correct English.

The first is more formal and the second is simpler. The second is probably the form that would be most used.

Answer (score -2):

Beneficiary is a noun.
Benefit and benefited are verbs.

I personally am a beneficiary is not common usage. It has a stilted, formal tone to it.
It is much more common to say I personally benefited, or even I benefited.